# How to get data sorted on an element's values using cts:element-attribute-values() function?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-10

**REQUIREMENT** : Get Employee IDs (*/Employee/@id*) matching the query in ascending order of joining date (*/Employee/JoiningDate*) as quickly as possible

**ENVIRONMENT** : MarkLogic DB has *1 million* Employee XMLs

**QUERY-1 [Runs very slow, but returns data in the correct order]**

```
let $fullQuery :=
    cts:and-query((
        cts:directory-query("/employee/", "infinity"),
        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","DeptName"), "Sales", ("case-insensitive")),
        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","SubDeptName"), "Micro", ("case-insensitive"))
    ))
let $queryOptions := ("unfiltered", cts:index-order(cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","JoiningDate"),("type=dateTime")), "ascending"))
return cts:search(/Employee, $fullQuery, $queryOptions)!fn:string(./@id) (: Using ! to get id's in sorted order. This seems to affect performance quite heavily. :)
```

**QUERY-2 [Runs very fast, but returns data in incorrect order]**

```
let $fullQuery :=
    cts:and-query((
        cts:directory-query("/employee/", "infinity"),
        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","DeptName"), "Sales", ("case-insensitive")),
        cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","SubDeptName"), "Micro", ("case-insensitive"))
    ))
let $queryOptions := ("concurrent")
return cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("Employee"), xs:QName("id"), (), $queryOptions, $fullQuery)
```

How to fulfil the **REQUIREMENT** using either of the above two approaches?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the path the $expression of the first cts:search param? `cts:search(/Employee/@id, $fullQuery, $queryOptions)`

Comment: @Mads Hansen, I would be surprised if it works, as, conceptually, element value queries won't match the XPath /Employee/@id as id attribute doesn't and can't have element nodes. Anyway, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Or add that path after the search, instead of simple mapping operator

Comment: @Mads Hansen, if you know for sure that it will work, can you explain why?

Comment: Reason behind using the simple mapping operator is to get id values in the expected sorted order. For some reason, I wasn't getting id values in the sorted order by using /@id after the cts:search expression.

Comment: Oh, you are right. With xpath it will be sorted in document order. Have to use simple mapping operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cts:value-co-occurrences` will let you order by one index while returning the values from another index at the same time.

e.g.

```
for $v in cts:value-co-occurrences(
  cts:element-reference(xs:QName("JoiningDate"),
  cts:element-attribute-reference(xs:QName("Employee"), xs:QName("id")),
  (), 
  $fullQuery
)
return $v/cts:value[2]/string(.)
```

Comment: it works! How the sorting works here? Is the result sorted only on the first reference? Does it ensure that data is always correctly sorted by JoiningDate?

Comment: The results are returned in index order of the first index reference, yes. Whichever collation that uses.